# Read URL parameter as variable in visual workflow

Tags: email, email-template, visual-workflow, flow, parameters

scenario is like this, marketing team sent blast email to campaign member. member receive the email invitation. if member want to confirm his attendance for the campaign, he can simply click the button on the email.

- i send email template to campaign member, for campaign attending confirmation
- in email template i have a flow link with campaign member id and campaign id parameter.
- if user click the flow link, it will update the Confirm__c (custom field) status from "not confirm" to "confirm"

the question is, can i save the parameter into variable in visual workflow?

if https://my.salesforce.com/flow/myFlow?CampaignId=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&CampaignMemberId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

can i save those param to flow? (CampaignId & CampaignMemberId)

Answer (score 1):

Of course. Inside your flow make sure the variables which you use on the url have input/output type set to ***Input***. The variable names must exactly match what you use the url.

Comment: So in your example, your flow variables must be CampaignId and CampaignMemberId